# How to reference a method from a class with < > and pass in variables

Tags: java

I'm trying to reference the method `shortestPathBetween(N from, N to)` from the class

```
public class DijkstraGraphAnalyzer<N extends Node<N, E>, E extends Edge<N, E>> implements GraphAnalyzer<N, E>
```

in the class `MainMenuController` to pass in variables so that the method can run on input derived from choiceboxes.

I've tried creating a local variable of the class but it then wants me to add the exact same parameters `<N, E>` to the `MainMenuController`

MainMenuController.java

```
public <MapPoint> List<MapPoint> shortestPathBetween(MapPoint from, MapPoint to) {
  from = (MapPoint) MainMenuController.source;
  to = (MapPoint) MainMenuController.target;
  List<MapPoint> shortestPathBetween = dga.shortestPathBetween(from, to);
  shortestPathBetween = shortestPathBetween(from, to);

  System.out.println("Source : \n" + from + " Target : \n" + to);

  return shortestPathBetween;
}
```

DijsktraGraphAnalyzer.java

```
public class DijkstraGraphAnalyzer<N extends Node<N, E>, E extends Edge<N, E>> implements GraphAnalyzer<N, E> {

    private final Graph<N, E> graph;
    // Store the default node/distance mapping for efficiency.
    private final Map<N, Double> defaultNodeDistanceMapping;
    private final Map<N, N> defaultPreviousNodeMapping;

    public DijkstraGraphAnalyzer(final Graph<N, E> graph) {
        this.graph = graph;
        this.defaultNodeDistanceMapping = new HashMap<N, Double>();
        this.defaultPreviousNodeMapping = new HashMap<N, N>();
        for (final N n : this.graph.getNodes()) {
            this.defaultNodeDistanceMapping.put(n, Double.MAX_VALUE);
            this.defaultPreviousNodeMapping.put(n, null);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public List<N> shortestPathBetween(N from, N to) {
        final Map<N, Double> nodeDistanceMapping = buildNodeDistanceMapping(from);
        final Map<N, N> previousNodeMapping = new HashMap<N, N>(defaultPreviousNodeMapping);

        final Set<N> unsettled = new HashSet<N>();
        unsettled.add(from); 
.......
```

Ideally, I want to be able to pass in two MapPoints into the method so that it can run in its respective class.

Comment: How `dga` is declared?

Comment: I agree, in order to allow me (or others) to add "more" meaningful answers, you might want to improve your question, for example along the lines of [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

This here:

```
public <MapPoint> List<MapPoint> shortestPathBetween(MapPoint from, MapPoint to)
```

Doesn't make any sense. If MapPoint is already an existing class, then the signature doesn't need any generics:

```
public List<MapPoint> shortestPathBetween(MapPoint from, MapPoint to)
```

If MapPoint is actually a type parameter, then you better name it according to conventions, like

```
public <T> List<T> shortestPathBetween(T from, T to)
```

Beyond that, I suggest you revisit how to use generics in Java, the official [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) is a good starting point.